# How to get the list of DAGS and their scheduled time from cloud composer (airflow environment) in GCP?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler, google-cloud-composer, airflow-2.x, airflow-api

I believe there can be a log for this, which stores all the dags and their respective data.
I need to have a list of dags with their schedule time, the expected code can be in any format, python or shell command.

Thanks.

Comment: You can run this command from cloud shell to list the dags `gcloud composer environments storage dags list --environment=ENVIRONMENT --location=LOCATION`. Let me know if it’s helpful or not?

Comment: It did not help, it gives the files present in dag folder but the requirement is to get the list of dags with their scheduled time.

Comment: Can you clarify more on your use case? Where do you want to store the output results when using Python code?

Comment: My use case is to find the schedule time for all dags and if not, then current state of dags, I am trying the "gcloud composer environments run my_environment --location us-central1 dags state" command however unable to get the output, can you help with that command?

Comment: It would be okay if you just print the output with python code

Comment: Hi @AniketGhole, If you find my answer helpful, please consider to accept & upvote it as per [Stack Overflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), helping more Stack contributors with their researches. If not, let me know so that I can improve the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To manually check the status of dags. You can follow these ways:

1. To get the status of Dags from GCP you can use [gcloud composer environments run](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/composer/environments/run) command.

   Example:

   ```
   gcloud composer environments run environment_name --location 'location_name' dags state -- dag_id -- execution_date
   ```
2. To get the status of Dags from Airflow CLI you can use [dag state](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html#state) or [dag list-runs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html#list-runs) command.
3. You can get the current status of the dags from the Airflow UI:

   You can go to Browse -> Task Instances and apply “state” filter to get the status of the DAGS, you can also include filters like DAG ID.